# Regd - Geting Bluetooth rssi value of Paired devices

Tags: android

Can we get Bluetooth Rssi value of paired devices in android progrmatically.

Thanks

Comment: Um yes, you don't even have to pair for that. And what is regd?

Comment: @TimCastelijns how,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read RSSI (Signal Strength) for connected devices.

Get Extra EXTRA_RSSI to obtain the RSSI from ACTION_FOUND intent.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            int  rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"  RSSI: " + rssi + "dBm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: ok,,But i need for Bluetooth paired devices.In this way I can get Bluetooth RSSI value of nearby devices.

Comment: @User why do you accept the answer if it's not what you need?

Comment: @Renaud *You can read RSSI (Signal Strength) for connected devices.* that is not what your code does. found and connected is not the same